# ¿Como eliminar un elemento de una lista que esta enlazada con otra sin perder ese dato en la otra lista?

Tags: python, poo

Hola amigos espero me puedan ayudar con esto.

tengo este objecto

```
class Player(Game):
"""docstring for Jugador"""
def __init__(self, name, sex):
    self.name = name
    self.sex = sex
    self.points = 0
    self.efectividad = 0
    self.wins = 0
    self.lose = 0
    self.rank = 0

def changeSex(self, sex):
    """ Change the Player Sex """
    self.sex = sex

def addPoints(self, points):
    """ Add points a player """
    self.points = points

def win(self):
    self.wins += 1

def lose(self):
    self.lose += 1
```

El cual se crea y se almacena en una lista con esta función

```
def addPlayer(self, name, sex):
    self.players.append( Player(name, sex) )
```

este método pertenece a esta clase

```
class Game(object):
"""docstring for Game"""
def __init__(self, rounds, name, mode, numberOfTables):
    super(Game, self).__init__()
    self.roundGame = 1
    self.rounds = rounds
    self.name = name
    self.mode = mode
    self.numberOfTables = numberOfTables
    self.tables = []
    self.pointsOfTheRound = []
    self.players = []
    self.ranking = []

def changeName(self, name):
    """ Change the Player name or Game name """
    self.name = name

def addPlayer(self, name, sex):
    self.players.append( Player(name, sex) )

def addPointsToRound(self, points):
    self.pointsOfTheRound.append( points )

def nextRound(self, roundGame):

    if len(self.tables) == self.numberOfTables:
        roundGame = "Ronda " + str(self.roundGame)
        pointsOfTheRound = {roundGame : self.tables}
        self.addPointsToRound(pointsOfTheRound)

        if (self.roundGame == self.rounds):
            print("Ultima Ronda") 
        elif (self.roundGame <= self.rounds ):
            self.roundGame += 1

        self.tables = []
    else:
        print("Introduzca los puntos de todas las mesas antes de avanzar de ronda")

def getCountOfPlayers(self):
    return len(self.players)

def getRaking(self):
    print(self.ranking)
```

luego de iniciar el juego y empezar a asignarse los puntos al avanzar de ronda, quiero hacer una tabla de jugadores en la cual, los jugadores se van a colocar en orden mayor puntuación a menor, es por eso que el objecto player tiene un atributo points y efectividad, si llegase a haber un jugador que tenga la misma puntuación que otro, se pasaría a evaluar la efectividad que tuvo este jugador contra la del otro durante la partida, mi problema es que cuando quiero evaluar quien es el mejor jugador para ir ordenando el ranking de mayor a menor, yo lo logro determinar el jugador que tiene mas puntos o mejor efectividad con esta función

```
def getBestPlayers(gameClass):
players, mayor = gameClass.players, 1

for i in range(gameClass.getCountOfPlayers() - 1):

    if i >= 1:

        if players[mayor].points > players[i - 1].points:
            mayor = mayor
        elif players[mayor].points == players[i - 1].points:

            if players[mayor].efectividad > players[i - 1].efectividad:
                mayor = mayor
            elif players[mayor].efectividad == players[i - 1].efectividad:
                print("Empate 1")
            else:
                mayor = i - 1

        else:
            mayor = i - 1

return mayor
```

Efectivamente retornara el jugador con mejor puntuación o mejor efectividad, pero si son 10 jugadores, tengo que ejecutar 10 veces la función para conseguir quien seria el siguiente jugador con mejor puntuación o efectividad y siempre me devolverá el mismo jugador, lo que yo pensé fue, tengo mi lista llamada ranking y en esta insertare el jugador que me arroje la función y tendre mi ranking, si se fijan el objeto `Game` ya contiene esta lista como atributo y hacia ella irán los jugadores que retorne la función, la cosa es que para que me arroje otro jugador diferente, a mi se me ocurrió usar el método `.pop()` de las listas y efectivamente me retorna el siguiente jugador con mejor ranking ya que no estaría el anterior en la lista, cuando reviso mi lista ranking, la tengo vacía y si reviso la lista de players, también la tengo vacía, ya que el método `.pop()` me elimina el objecto player de ambas listas y ese es mi problema.

Quiero obtener los jugadores de `self.players`, que es mi lista de jugadores y asignarlos a `players = gameClass.players` mi lista local de la función `getBestPlayers(gameClass)` y que al yo aplicar el método `.pop()` a `players` solo se elimine de esta lista y no de la lista `self.players` de la clase `Game`, ¿Como puedo lograr esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te he entendido bién creo que te estas complicando sin necesidad, Python ya posee la capacidad de ordenar objetos usando sus atributos mediante `sort` y `operator.attrgetter` de forma simple (ver [documentación](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#operator-module-functions)). Para mostrarlo voy a simplificar tu código para que sea facilmente reproducible el ejemplo:

```
import operator

class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, points, efectividad):
        self.name = name
        self.points = points
        self.efectividad = efectividad


datos = (('Juan', 10, 5),
         ('Maria', 10, 4),
         ('Carlos', 15, 14),
         ('Laura', 15, 16),
         ('Andres', 5, 4),
         ('Lucia', 8, 3),
         ('Mario', 5, 5))

jugadores = [Player(nombre, puntos, efect) for (nombre, puntos, efect) in datos]

#Imprimimos los jugadores para comprobar su orden actual
print('\nJUGADORES SIN ORDENAR:')
for j in jugadores:
    print('{}:\n    Puntos: {}.\n    Efectividad: {}.'.format(j.name, j.points, j.efectividad))

#Ordenamos
jugadores.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('points', 'efectividad'), reverse = True)


#Volvemos a imprimir la lista para ver el resultado
print('\nJUGADORES ORDENADOS:')
for j in jugadores:
    print('{}:\n    Puntos: {}.\n    Efectividad: {}.'.format(j.name, j.points, j.efectividad))
```

La clave y lo que puedes usar tu es:

```
import operator

jugadores.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('points', 'efectividad'), reverse = True)
```

Esto ordena de mayor a menor los objetos en la lista (in place) usando primero su atributo `points` y si este es igual usa el atributo `efectividad`. Si quisieras una copia ordenada de la lista en vez de ordenar la lista in place usa `sorted`:

```
ordenados = sorted(jugadores, key=operator.attrgetter('points', 'efectividad'), reverse = True)
```

**La salida es:**

> ```
> JUGADORES SIN ORDENAR:
> Juan:
>     Puntos: 10.
>     Efectividad: 5.
> Maria:
>     Puntos: 10.
>     Efectividad: 4.
> Carlos:
>     Puntos: 15.
>     Efectividad: 14.
> Laura:
>     Puntos: 15.
>     Efectividad: 16.
> Andres:
>     Puntos: 5.
>     Efectividad: 4.
> Lucia:
>     Puntos: 8.
>     Efectividad: 3.
> Mario:
>     Puntos: 5.
>     Efectividad: 5.
>
> JUGADORES ORDENADOS:
> Laura:
>     Puntos: 15.
>     Efectividad: 16.
> Carlos:
>     Puntos: 15.
>     Efectividad: 14.
> Juan:
>     Puntos: 10.
>     Efectividad: 5.
> Maria:
>     Puntos: 10.
>     Efectividad: 4.
> Lucia:
>     Puntos: 8.
>     Efectividad: 3.
> Mario:
>     Puntos: 5.
>     Efectividad: 5.
> Andres:
>     Puntos: 5.
>     Efectividad: 4.
> ```

Aparte de esto, tu problema inicial se debe a que necesitas una copia muerta de tu lista `self.players` ya que hacer algo como `players = gameClass.players` lo unico que hace es que tanto `self.players`como `players` compartan la misma referencia (apuntan al mismo objeto). Esto hace que modificar una variable modifique la otra ya que apuntan al mismo objeto.

Para solventar estos problemas usa [copy.deepcopy()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
import copy
players = copy.deep.copy(gameClass.players)
```

Ahora ambas listas son objetos distintos y también los objetos que contienen lo son. Eliminar o modificar cualquier objeto en una de las listas no altera a la otra. No obstante, es muy ineficiente comparado con lo anterior ya que no solo duplicas todos los objetos en memoria, además necesitas de varios `for` y el uso de metodos como `pop` que hacen mucho más ineficiente este método.

Comment: Como me encanta esta pagina jajajaja, si veo que me estuve complicando demasiado, no soy muy experto en python, apenas voy por 3er semestre de la universidad xD, el metodo .sort() de las listas me sirve, el sorted() me entrega la lista pero desordenada. Esta es la salia que me produce la funcion sorted

Comment: `Jugador: Player 1 y Puntos: 99 y Efectividad 73

Jugador: Player 2 y Puntos: 91 y Efectividad 70

Jugador: Player 3 y Puntos: 48 y Efectividad 12

Jugador: Player 4 y Puntos: 50 y Efectividad 93

Jugador: Player 5 y Puntos: 10 y Efectividad 97

Jugador: Player 6 y Puntos: 38 y Efectividad 93

Jugador: Player 7 y Puntos: 47 y Efectividad 39

Jugador: Player 8 y Puntos: 74 y Efectividad 26

Jugador: Player 9 y Puntos: 91 y Efectividad 31

Jugador: Player 10 y Puntos: 20 y Efectividad 13`

Comment: @EnriqueMora pues no se que puede estar pasando porque tanto el método `sort` como el built-in `sorted` son identicos en este caso. Lo he testeado y en mi caso el resultado es correcto. Eso si, asegurate que estas imprimiendo la lista ordenada que retorna `sorted`, ya que la original no la ordena. En mi ejemplo (`ordenados = sorted(jugadores, key=operator.attrgetter('points', 'efectividad'), reverse = True)`) la lista `ordenados` si estará ordenada pero no `jugadores`. A diferencia del método `list.sort`, `sorted` no ordena la lista original in-place solo retorna una copia ordenada. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no voy a agregar mucho a lo que te dijo @FJSevilla, el ejemplo que te  puedo dar es el siguiente:

```
class Player():

  def __init__(self, nombre, points, efectividad):
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.points = points
    self.efectividad = efectividad

  def __str__(self):
    return "{} ({},{})".format(self.nombre, self.points, self.efectividad)

class Game():

  def __init__(self):
    self.players = list()

  def add_player(self, nombre, points, efectividad):
    self.players.append(Player(nombre, points, efectividad))

  def get_best_players_list(self):
    self.players.sort(key=lambda x: (x.points, x.efectividad, x.nombre), reverse=True)
    return self.players

g = Game()

g.add_player("juan", 100, 90)
g.add_player("alberto", 55, 80)
g.add_player("luis", 100, 60)
g.add_player("rolando", 100, 60)
g.add_player("pedro", 210, 60)

for p in g.get_best_players_list():
   print(p)
```

Es una versión muy simplificada de tu código. La lógica para obtener una lista ordenada se encuentra en el método `get_best_players_list` que usa una función `lambda` para definir sobre que atributos se ordenará:

```
self.players.sort(key=lambda x: (x.points, x.efectividad, x.nombre), reverse=True)
```

el nombre en el orden seguramente está de más, por lo único que lo dejaría es si dos jugadores mantienen los mismos puntos y efectividad y queremos que no varíen la posición en la lista

La alternativa de @FJSevilla de usar `operator.attrgetter` entiendo que es mejor y más rápida. El orden aplica directamente a la lista `self.players`, por lo que si necesitás una copia que no sea una referencia tal como te mendionaron en la respuesta anterior hay que ir al `deepcopy`. Agregué a la clase `Player` un metodó muy útil `__str__` que permite construir una representación del objeto, de esta forma un `print(objeto)` mostrará una información más amigable. La salida final sería algo así:

```
pedro (210,60)
juan (100,90)
rolando (100,60)
luis (100,60)
alberto (55,80)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder y `def __str__(self):
    return "{} ({},{})".format(self.nombre, self.points, self.efectividad)` ty por el metodo